# How I can matching a checkbox with a textfile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I try to verify if the Simulink checkbox is selected, and if it is to replace in `installer.ini` file next rows:

```
product=all => #product=all
#product=Simulink=> product=Simulink
```

This thing I tried to do with the next code :

```
public void Simulink_Checked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
            string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
            var lin = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(path, "installer.ini")).ToArray();

            CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                var product = lin.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "product=all", "#product=all"));
                var product_tool = product.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, "#product=Simulink", "product=Simulink"));
                File.WriteAllLines(installerfilename, product_tool);
            }

        }
```

but doesn't work.
That means :the Rows remain

```
product=all
#product=Simulink
```

I want to mention: the `checkbox Simulink` it's a element of checkedListBox1, and I want to do the same thing with all elements, but to understand I begin with `Simulink` .
How I can do this code to work ?

Comment: "does not work" is not enough of explanation for good SO question. I'd recommend debugging your code first to clarify what exactly going wrong - than update the post.

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in debugger? Have you checked values of each variable - did they look ok? Are there any exceptions (if yes - provide exact message)? It is very hard to guess what is going wrong - maybe you even failed to wire up this event handler to correct button - how SO folks would know?

Comment: when I put break points, and the code is in debugger, It do not get on this part of code

Comment: it's possible to have the problem in  FormDesign, in events, because there in column SelectesIndexChanged I have checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged ??

Comment: but if there I put Simulink_checked I can't see how I will do the conection with other check boxes

Comment: There are many questions on ["how to specify same handler for event in WinForms".](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+specify+same+handler+for+event+in+WinForms).

Comment: Here I have all I want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711545/how-i-can-modify-a-text-file-when-a-checkbox-is-checked, you can help me please ???